# Boost_LIBRARYDIR is not the correct spelling

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I am trying to add boost to my CMakeLists.txt file. However, I am getting this error:

```
CMake Error at /export/home/yhe/local/share/cmake-3.3/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:393 (message):
  ERROR: Boost_LIBRARYDIR is not the correct spelling.  The proper spelling
  is BOOST_LIBRARYDIR.
```

I am using cmake3.3.2 and command:

```
find_package(Boost 1.55.0 COMPONENTS atomic REQUIRED)
```

This is the file:

```
  1 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)                                                                                                                                                                         
  2 SET(CMAKE_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_LINCLUDE_DIR} "/export/home/thirdparty/boost/1.55.0/")                                                                                                                          
  3 SET(CMAKE_LIBRARYDIR ${CMAKE_LIBRARYDIR} "/export/home/thirdparty/boost/1.55.0/lib/AS5")                                                                                                                      
  4 message(${Boost_LIBRARYDIR})                                                                                                                                                                                  
  5 find_package(Boost COMPONENTS atomic REQUIRED)
```

It turns out the Boost_LIBRARYDIR was defined when I call cmake. Removing the  CMakeCache.txt file, the problem goes away. I guess I might have set Boost_LIBRARYDIR when I was trying to make it work and it got cached. FindBoost.cmake will exit when Boost_LIBRARYDIR has been defined. However, this error message is really misleading.

Comment: What is your problem? You say the problem goes away after clearing the cache.

Comment: Yes, find_package requires Boost_LIBRARY undefined. However, it was defined on my system in the Cache File.  Looking at the FindBoost.cmake, the spellCheck is intended to make sure people don't confuse BOOST as Boost and accidentally set Boost_LIBRARY, however, the error message is kind of misleading. They should say "Boost_LIBRARYDIR set, are you sure you are not trying to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR?".

Comment: That is exactly what it is saying. Also, it seems to me that this should be bug report for CMake, not a question for stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a questionable bug report, no a question.

Answer (score 0):

`BOOST_ROOT, BOOST_LIBRARYDIR, BOOST_INCLUDEDIR` variables are case sensitive.

I am using cmake along with Boost.

Below the cmake I am using. Note that I am compiling using MSVC 12

```
set(BOOST_ROOT C:/boost/boost_1_55_0/)
set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR C:/boost/boost_1_55_0/boost)
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR C:/boost/boost_1_55_0/lib64-msvc-12.0)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_COMPILER -vc120)
find_package(Boost 1.55.0 COMPONENTS atomic REQUIRED)
```

Comment: Even if I set BOOST_ROOT ... etc., I am still getting this error. Only if I comment out the check spell on FindBoost.cmake, I am able to pass through. I am now think if my version of cmake has some bug ...

Comment: Do you have an example of your cmake ?